# How to fix process.nextTick is not a function with Calgolia places.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've installed Calgolia places.js in my Angular 7 project by NPM and I have an issue. I've created a form and this input should be one of form fields.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <pre style="color: white; background-color: #000;">
        Value: {{myForm.value | json}}
      </pre>
      <mat-form-field class="first-form-half-width">
        <input id="address-input" matInput placeholder="Pick up:" formControlName="pickUp">
      </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And I'd like to get the input value into my JSON. But I have a problem - when I type 'Los A' in my input and I press 'Los Angeles' into autocomplete I have text content in my input 'Los Angeles' but in my JSON it's still 'Los A'. But if I type something after 'Los Angeles', for example 'abc', JSON updates and there is 'Los Angelesabc'. Also when I click on my input I have an error in console

```
ERROR TypeError: process.nextTick is not a function
    at nextTick.js:9
    at immediate (index.js:94)
    at Input.trigger (event_emitter.js:76)
    at Input.onFocus [as _onFocus] (input.js:100)
    at HTMLInputElement.proxyFn (zepto.js:1033)
    at HTMLInputElement.handler.proxy (zepto.js:1007)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15724
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15772
next @ core.js:17771
schedulerFn @ core.js:13515
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13499
(anonymous) @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17258
onHandleError @ core.js:17321
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:198
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1781
```

Is there any possibility to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Constants such as 'window' don't exist on a node.js app, as it's not situated within a viewport. Create a placeholder function like the following, to overcome the error:

```
(window as any).process = {
   env: { DEBUG: undefined },
   nextTick: function() {
     return null;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`process.nextTick` is a function that only exists in node.js. It does not exist in the browser, hence the error that you are getting. What is happening here is that you are including in the browser a library that is meant only for node.js.

It's hard to tell exactly which library this is without knowing more about which libraries you are using and how you are using them.

---

**EDIT** If you can't figure out what is happening, it is just as easy to monkey patch the nextTick function in the browser. [See the sample here.](https://timnew.me/blog/2014/06/23/process-nexttick-implementation-in-browser/)

Essentially, you are just aliasing `setTimeout(fn, 0)` to `nextTick`. There are a few complexities and corner cases, but the idea is simple.

I'm not sure why `nextTick` isn't being monkey patched during the build process and maybe you should look at why. But if you can't figure it out, it's safe to monkey patch it yourself.

Comment: I am getting the same error while using `browserify-zlib` in angular 7. Can you tell me any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can also polyfill the process dependency:

> npm install process

```js
import * as process from "process";
window.process = process;
```

Using something like `windows.process.nextTick = setTimeout` resulted in a very bad performance for me.